# Special characters in Localizable.strings not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I include special characters in the Localizable.strings, the translation won't work:

```
"Ödla" = "Lizzard"
```

In order to get it to work, I have to replace the special characters:

```
"&Ouml;dla" = "Lizzard"
```

.. which is a read hassle. 
Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually it's the reverse, you do `"Lizzard" = "Ödla"` because it's "Key" = "ValueTranslated" And in the File Inspector (right panel), what's the encoding set? Why not use "No explicit Encoding"?

Comment: Thanks for input, but this didn't work.